# How to show join 2 mysql tables?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have 2 tables on MySQL: phy and VM.

Here is the phy table:

[image: phy table]

and here is the VM table:

[image: The VM table]

I want to get a result like an image below:

[image: expected result]

I type the command below like this:

```
select ip, name, brand, vm.mem, vm.mem FROM phy JOIN vm ON phy.ip = vm.ip
```

but the result is like this:

[image: results obtained]

what command do I have to type in order for me to get the result I want?

Comment: You're selecting `vm.mem` twice. Try `SELECT p.ip, p.name, p.brand, vm.mem, vm.hdd FROM phy p JOIN vm ON p.ip = vm.ip`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM phy
JOIN vm USING (ip)
```

The query assumes that `ip` is defined as primary/unique key in both tables.

The query won't return the data for `ip` if it is present in one of these tables only. If you need such data then you'd use

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ( SELECT ip FROM phy
       UNION 
       SELECT ip FROM vm ) total
LEFT JOIN phy USING (ip)
LEFT JOIN vm USING (ip)
```

Or, if the presence is optional in one table only, use (for optional presence in `vm`, for example)

```
SELECT *
FROM phy
LEFT JOIN vm USING (ip)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT phy.id, phy.name, phy.brand, vm.mem, vm.hdd
FROM phy
INNER JOIN vm ON phy.id=vm.id;
```